# What do "type" and types 0,1,2 means in Ethers.js?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, ethers.js

What does the Type mean & what do Type 0,1,2 signifies in Ethers.js?
I only found https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2718#transactions this
as relevant. can someone please help me out on this one?

```
hash : ' 0x3dd67f90200eb9902fb64ee
type : 2 ,
accessList : [ ] ,
blockHash : ' 0xe295188fa2aa6e9a5b
blockNumber : 15472730 ,
transaction Index : 63 ,
confirmations : 2 ,
from : ' 0x227c4Bf958A9Ab93EA04ee
```

[image: Picture of Console here]

Answer (score 2):

From: [transaction-types-on-ethereum](https://blog.mycrypto.com/new-transaction-types-on-ethereum)

> Ethereum has different transaction types that specify what a
> transaction should do. For example, sending Ether to an address,
> deploying a contract, etc.
>
> Before the recent Berlin network upgrade, there were essentially four
> different transaction "types" in Ethereum

Previously, Ethereum had one format for transactions. Each transaction consists of a nonce, gas price, gas limit, to address, value, data, v, r, and s. These fields are RLP-encoded, to look something like this:

```
 RLP([nonce, gasPrice, gasLimit, to, value, data, v, r, s])
```

> EIP-2718 defines a new generalised envelope for typed transactions. In
> the new standard, transactions look like this:

```
 TransactionType || TransactionPayload
```

> TransactionType: a number between 0 and 0x7f, for a total of 128
> possible transaction types.

This is the use case:

> This new approach makes it possible for new EIPs to introduce a
> transaction type without introducing more unnecessary complexity in
> the existing transaction format, and it makes it a lot easier for the
> different Ethereum tools (clients, libraries) to distinguish between
> different transactions.

Read about TransactionType-2 [what-does-eip-1559-change/](https://2miners.com/blog/ethereum-london-hardfork-what-does-eip-1559-change/)

> The response to the high and unpredictable transaction fees in
> Ethereum was EIP-1559. It introduced a new concept – the base cost of
> gas – a fixed value, smoothly changing depending on the network load
> (if the expected transaction numbers are low, the base cost smoothly
> decreases, as soon as there are more of them – smoothly increases).
> From now on, whenever a new type of transaction is sent, the base cost
> of gas multiplied by the amount of gas spent is always used for
> calculation, no more and no less. This eliminates the possibility of
> errors with sending transactions with disproportionately large
> commissions, and it is easier for the wallet programs to calculate the
> cost of commissions, as they are formed according to a fairly simple
> and predictable scheme. The new type of transaction is called a “type
> 2 transaction,” and canonical transactions are called a “type 0
> transaction”